# Setting up profile picture upload for a user

Tags: node.js, multer, cloudinary

So I came across a video using multer and cloudinary to upload pictures for post. I tried to copy and implement in my code but I'm getting the "MulterError: Unexpected field" not sure why our how to fix. I'm trying to give the user the option to upload their own picture and if not the server should render the default picture.

```
**var express = require("express");
var router  = express.Router();
var passport = require("passport");
var User = require("../models/user");
var Post = require("../models/post");
require('dotenv').config();
var multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    filename: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.originalname);
    }
});
var imageFilter = function (req, file, cb) {
    if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/i)) {
        return cb(new Error('Only image files are allowed!'), false);
    }
    cb(null, true);
};
var upload = multer({storage: storage, fileFilter: imageFilter});

var cloudinary = require('cloudinary');
cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: 'dxshkwriz',
    api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET
});

//root route
router.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("landing");
});

router.get('/home',function(req, res){
    res.render('index')
});

router.get('/team', function(req, res){
    res.render('team')
});

router.get('/give', function(req, res){
    res.render('give')
});
router.post('/give', function(req, res){
    res.redirect('/home')
});
// show register form
router.get("/register", function(req, res){
   res.render("sign-up"); 
});

//handle sign up logic
router.post("/register", upload.single('image'), function(req, res){
    cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.file.path, function(result){
        req.body.image = result.secure_url
    })
    var image = req.body.image ? req.body.image : "/Images/d-avatar.jpg";
    var newUser = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        description: req.body.description,
        email: req.body.email,
        location: req.body.location,
        avatar: image
    });
    User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err, user){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            // req.flash('error', err.message);
            return res.render("sign-up");
        };
        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
            // req.flash('error', 'Welcome to our forums' + user.username);
           res.redirect("/forums"); 
        });
    });
});

//show login form
router.get("/login", function(req, res){
   res.render("login"); 
});

//handling login logic
router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", 
    {
        successRedirect: "/forums",
        failureRedirect: "/login"
    }), function(req, res){
});

// logout route
router.get("/logout", function(req, res){
   req.logout();
    // req.flash('succes', 'Logged Out')
   res.redirect("/forums");
});

router.get('/users/:id', function(req, res){
    User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundUser){
        if(err){
            res.redirect('back')
        } else {
            Post.find().where('author.id').equals(foundUser._id).exec(function (err, posts){
            if(err){
                res.redirect('back');
            } else {
                res.render('user/show', {user:foundUser, posts: posts});
            }
            })
        }
    })
})

module.exports = router;**
```

Comment: Is the form field in the frontend called 'image' or something else? you'll get an error from multer if the field name doesn't match

Comment: I did forget to change that at first but even with everything matching still getting the error.